Terminating sub orchestrator in azure durable function
Is it possible to terminate sub-orchrastrators. How is it done?
Scenario. I have an orchestrator calling 2 sub-orchestrators
I want to terminate just one of them. Is it possible? I use python.

Can you provide your code that you have tried?

You cannot directly terminate one sub orchestrator and run another at the same time. One way is using if else statement in Main Orchestrator as below:
@rithapp.orchestration_trigger(context_name="context")
def rith_main_orc(context):
    val = []
    rithrun_suborc1 = True  
    rithrun_suborc2 = False 
    if rithrun_suborc1:
        val_1 = context.call_sub_orchestrator("rith_sub_orc1")
        val.append(val_1)
    if rithrun_suborc2:
        val_2 = context.call_sub_orchestrator("rith_sub_orc2")
        val.append(val_2)
    ri_out = yield context.task_all(val) if val else []
    result = {}
    if rithrun_suborc1:
        result["test1"] = ri_out[0] if ri_out else None
    if rithrun_suborc2:
        result["test2"] = ri_out[1] if len(ri_out) > 1 else None
    return result

@rithapp.orchestration_trigger(context_name="context")
def rith_sub_orc1(context):
    return "Rithwik From sub 1"

@rithapp.orchestration_trigger(context_name="context")
def rith_sub_orc2(context):
    return "Rithwik From sub 2"

Here, I am giving true/false value directly(you can send those values to main orchestrator) in main orchestrator and if the value is true it executes the sub orchestrator, if it is false it will not execute it.
Output:
If  sub 1  is True:

if both are True:

